# How to add createdByID field and lastModifiedByID

Tags: acumatica, erp

I was working on with the "Get" method in Acumatica API, I successfully pull the records from the API however there is no userID of the creator and modifier.

[image: Webservice Endpoints]

I tried to find the `createdBy` and `ModifiedBy` in the dropdown, but there is none.

How to add the `UserID` of creator and modifier on the web service endpoint so that these fields will be parts of the Get response?

Answer (score 1):

You can't select these fields with the dropdown, however you can type the fields name in the grid.

[image]